How to offset navbar hide on scroll while hero section is visible?
I have a simple function that hides the navbar when the user scrolls down the page, and shows it again when scrolling up. I would like to offset this, so it is effectively disabled while the hero section is visible in the viewport, exactly like the Chrome website.
Is this achievable with JS or jQuery or do I need to use a library like GSAP?


var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-50px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: top 0.3s;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>

  <div id="navbar">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>

  <div style="padding:15px 15px 2500px;font-size:30px;margin-top:30px;">
    <p><b>I would like to disable the navbar hide/show function while this section is visible in the viewport. I would like to disable the navbar hide/show function while this section is visible in the viewport. I would like to disable the navbar hide/show function while this section is visible in the viewport. I would like to disable the navbar hide/show function while this section is visible in the viewport. I would like to disable the navbar hide/show function while this section is visible in the viewport. I would like to disable the navbar hide/show function while this section is visible in the viewport. I would like to disable the navbar hide/show function while this section is visible in the viewport.</b></p>
    <p>Scroll down to see the navbar hide/show effect</p>
    <p>Scroll up to show the navbar.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor dummy text sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
      aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor dummy text sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
      aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>




You might find JavaScript's Intersection Observer API useful.
